# Group Theory: relation between subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Can anyone tell me why if two subgroups H and H' of a group G (not necessarily finite) called isometrics if the H∩H' has finite index towards H and H' then isometry is a relation of equivalence for the subgroups of G?

Comment: How can Mathematica answer this?

Comment: You are using wrong terminology, this relation between subgroups of $G$ is called *commensurability*. What did you try to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know the definition of an equivalence relation? Have you succeeded in verifying any part of that definition in this case?